# filter out atlas pages with no data in QGIS 3

Tags: print-composer, qgis-3, atlas

I am printing maps using the atlas to display layers with point data.  Some of the areas have no points in them.

Is it possible to suppress these using the filter options.  I could not figure out how.

i.e. don't generate the map unless the area contains one or more points in the area.

Comment: Are you aware that you can use an expression to filter the atlas? If so, what filters have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: Yes, i saw that but could not figure out how to constuct an appropriate filter

Comment: How many areas containing points do you have? If 'not too many' then you could filter by the area feature. For example if your Coverage feature is 'County' with field 'COUNTYCODE', you could set the filter like this:  "COUNTYCODE"='3' OR  "COUNTYCODE"='8' OR  "COUNTYCODE"='12' ... etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the plugin: refFunctions

Plugin description: "install the plugin to provide a 'Reference' group under field calculator with function for analytical or spatial reference to features in other layers"

Now set up a filter with this expression:

> intersecting_geom_count('PointsLayerName')>0

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is you could do a quick 'Join' of your polygon feature to a common field of your point feature then set the 'Filter With' in the Atlas tab to an expression using the joined field where the "joined_field" > 0 or "joined_field" is not null or similar.